# how to get active directory domain name on Mac via Terminal

Tags: macos, active-directory

basically i am trying to get via Terminal user principal name: username@full.name.of.activedomain.com
in Windows i can run "whoami /upn" and it will output everything. or nothing if user is not under Active Directory. so whoami for Windows works like a charm for me.
on Mac i found a command called "HOSTNAME". and there is also an alias to it - $HOSTNAME. if end user is binded to Active Directory - will it output its name? in other words - i would then could call this command:
echo $USER@$HOSTNAME to get the user principal name...

or maybe there is some different command or alias which i can use in Terminal? please help.

Answer (score 1):

I know probably this is too late. Still it might help someone in the future.

You can use "klist" command to retrieve the userPrincipalName for the current logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

Piece of script might help you to find out upn on OSX:

```
domainName=`echo show com.apple.opendirectoryd.ActiveDirectory |
scutil | grep DomainNameFlat | awk '{print $3}'`
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "Failed to get domain name, exiting script"
    exit 1
fi

if [ -z $domainName ]
then
     echo "Failed to get domain name, exiting script"
     exit 1
fi

echo "AD Domain name: $domainName "

userName=`id -u -nr`
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
     echo "Failed to get user name, exiting script"
     exit 1
fi

echo "User name: $userName"

upn=`dscl "/Active Directory/$domainName/All Domains" -read
            /Users/$userName userPrincipalName`
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "Failed to get user's upn, exiting script"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: What kind of script is this? How would you run this?

Answer (score -2):

The above is a BASH script. Ideally, it needs a she-bang as the first line. I have not tested the above script, but dscl is the "Directory Service Command Line" utility.

## !/usr/bin/env bash