# How to fetch username of the user who is logged into AD domain on OSX using objective C

Tags: macos, cocoa, active-directory, domaincontroller

Is there a way to find the username (User Principal Name or samaccountname) of the user who is using my app and is logged into an AD domain? 
Can we also find which domain is the user connected to programmatically?

`dsconfigad -show` command line does display the domain but not the username.

I cannot rely on `NSUsername() or NSFullUserName()` functions as user can manually change those.

Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: this bash example might give you a hint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22277761/how-to-get-active-directory-domain-name-on-mac-via-terminal.  Looks like the magic lies in using `dscl`

Comment: here's a C# cookbook that might be helpful if the APIs are similar: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C#27